# Unity - Post process foreground, but leave background as is

Tags: unity

I am using Unity 2019.3.5f1 and I am using the Universal Render Pipeline (URP).

I am trying to use the post processing in URP for the foreground only (in my case, the players), and I want the leave the background (which in my case, is just a quad with a texture), as is.

I have tried using the Camera Stack but it wont work for me because the overlay camera can't have post processing effects according to the documentation.

The only solution that I could come up with is create the some sort of custom render which:

1. Render the background to buffer A.
2. Render the foreground to buffer B, and save the depth.
3. Combine the two using a shader that gets both textures, and the depth texture, and based on the depth, takes buffer A or buffer B.

The problem with this I believe is that I cant use it with the post processing for Unity.

Any idea what I can do?

**EDIT**:

I tried another thing in Unity which seem to not be working (might be a bug):

1. I created 3 cameras: Foreground Camera, Depth Camera (only render the foreground), and a Background Camera.
2. I set up the Depth camera so it will render to a render texture and, indeed now I have a render texture with the proper depth I need.

Now, from here everything went wrong, there seem to be odd things happening when using Unity new Post processing (the built in one):

1. The Foreground Camera is set to Tag=MainCamera, and when I enable `Post Processing` and add an effect, indeed we can see it. (as expected)
2. The Background Camera is essentially a duplicate of the Foreground one, but with Tag=Untagged, I use the same options (enabled Post).

Now, the expected thing is we see the Background Camera with effects like Foreground, but no:

1. When using `Volume Mask` on my background layer, the Post processing just turns off, no effect at all no matter what (and I have set my background the `Background` layer).
2. When I disable the Foreground Camera (or remove its tag) and set the Background Camera to MainCamera, still nothing changes, the post still wont work.
3. When I set `Volume Mask` to `Default` (or everything), **the result is shown ONLY in the scene view**, I tried rendering the camera to a `RenderTexture` but still, you clearly see no effect applied!

Comment: Post-processing, by nature, happens after everything in your scene has been composited into a single image. So often by then, we've lost information that distinguishes player pixels from background. Can you show us an example of what specific effect(s) you want to apply to your players? There might be simpler ways to apply those effects selectively.

Comment: @DMGregory well, I don't really want to limit my designers use of the effects, so basically most of these: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/post-processing-bloom.html

Comment: Unfortunately there's likely no one solution that will get you every effect in the post processing stack. Many of the effects — like Bloom — need to influence pixels outside the object's silhouette, so a stencil mask won't work with them. Others need to preserve background pixels that have since been drawn over, or change the way the colour is blended with the background — something you can't do after it's already composited into one image. Can you ask your designers for what visual look they want first, and ask about that? If they need more later, you can always ask a second question.

Comment: @DMGregory I just got off the phone with the lead designer, we confirmed we will only need effects that are changing the looks (colors mainly, color adjustments, color curves, etc..), nothing like Bloom, Lens Distortion etc..

Comment: I think I got a solution, but it will not work for all cases (in my case, it will), I created 3 cameras, Foreground, Depth (of foreground), and background, I use the depth to separate the foreground from the background, the problem is the post processing effect only work for ALL game objects and layering does not seem to be working for now (I mean layering of the post processing effects, not culling)

Comment: Great, edit your question to demonstrate the colour effects you need, and you should be able to get answers much faster. Those types of effects are generally easy to mask to particular objects/regions with a stencil, so you should have good options available.